# Detecting a form.submit() performed via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

In my page there is a frame that belongs to the same domain. The content of this frame is varied and relatively unpredictable. Whenever a user clicks a button (inside the frame) that performs a post, I need to execute a function that performs some UI tasks. The problem is that I cannot edit the source of these frames for reasons beyond my control. Some of these buttons are simple form submit buttons, but others do not directly submit the form, but instead have an onclick handler that performs some checks and *might* submit.

Here is the problem: How do I detect if one of these onclick handlers called form.submit()? If there's no handler, then obviously I can set up a handler for onsubmit(), but is not the case for all of these buttons.

This is my code so far:

```
function addEventBefore(element, type, before, after) {
  var old = element['on' + type] || function() {};
  before = before  || function() {};
  after = after || function() {};
  element['on' + type] = function () { 
    before();
    old();//I can't modify this old onclick handler
    after();
  };
}

function setup() {
  console.log('setup');
}


function takedown() {
// In this method, I want to know if old() caused a form submit
  console.log('takedown');
}

function $includeFrames(jQuery, selector) {
    return jQuery(selector).add(jQuery('iframe').contents().find(selector));
}

var a = $includeFrames($, 'input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this)[0];
  addEventBefore(elem, 'click', setup, takedown);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me came from a friend of mine. The solution is to shim the form.submit() function.

```
$(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myform');
    el.submit = function(fn) {
        return function() {
            myFunctionGoesHere();
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }(el.submit);
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hW6Z4/9/

Answer (score 0):

In the onload event of the iframe you'll need to hook up an event listener to each form in the iframed page. You need to do this on every load, as each fresh page needs new listeners.

```
$("#someIframe").on('load',function() {
    $(this).contents().find("form").each(function() {
        $(this).on('submit',function() {... your code...})
    })
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working for me, do you see what I'm doing wrong in this example? http://jsfiddle.net/hW6Z4/ Both buttons should trigger the alert, but only one of them is. The JavaScript submit is not being caught.

Comment: You could overwrite the form's action, then trigger the action after you run your own code: var oldAction = `$(this).attr('action');
$(this).attr('action','javascript:alert("##")');`

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing, the problem for me is that if the form called javascript when the submit button was clicked, I don't know if that javascript called form.submit() or not. I want to know if it's possible to determine that.